# Xamarin Prism binding same command in multiple views

Tags: forms, xamarin, prism

I've a page view which has TabView and each tabview item is a separate view, containing list.

```
<TabView>
        <TabViewItem HeaderText="Comments">
            <TabViewItem.Content>
                    <local:CommentsListView/>
            </TabViewItem.Content>
        </TabViewItem>

        <TabViewItem HeaderText="Stock">
            <TabViewItem.Content>
                <local:StockListView/>
            </TabViewItem.Content>
        </TabViewItem>

        <TabViewItem HeaderText="Labour">
            <TabViewItem.Content>
                <local:LabourListView/>
            </TabViewItem.Content>
        </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

In each child view I've enabled pulldown and pulldown command in each view is pointing to the same 'RefreshCommand'. I want RefreshCommand to be called once no matter from which view pulldown was performed.

Problem is that if I have say 5 child views then refresh command is called 5 times. Obviously I could bind 5 different commands which calls the same method, but would be nice if I could reuse same command.

Is this possible?

Edit: added sample of view in each tab. They all are the same except pointing to different ItemSource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Controls"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Converters"
             x:Class="CommentsListView">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:NegateBooleanConverter x:Key="inverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <custom:ObjectGridView
        x:Name="commentsListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding CommentsList}"
        IsPullToRefreshEnabled="{Binding InEditMode, Converter={StaticResource inverter}}"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing, Mode=TwoWay}"
        PullToRefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        RowTapCommand="{Binding CommentTapCommand}"
        ShowAddButton="True"
        AddButtonVisible="{Binding InEditMode}"
        AddButtonCommand="{Binding AddButtonCommand}"/>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Hi, not understanding too much about *call 5 times* . You could share some ViewModel code and binding code to exaplain that. In addition, each `ListView` define one `RefreshCommand`, and use different commands for each  `ListView`.

Comment: I've added a sample of view which is basically the same in each tab, only difference is ItemSource is pointing to different data. As you can see, all PullDown commands are binding to same RefreshCommand.
So in ViewModel RefreshCommand is called 3 times if there is 3 views as per sample above.

Comment: Okey, what's the definition of `custom:ObjectGridView`? From your shared code can not explain where problem is.